# Django multistep form wizard model form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

Is there any way to use a Form Wizard in Admin interface for add/edit Models.
*(using Django 1.5.2)*
for example:

```
--models.py--
    class AModel(models.Model):
        fieldA = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        fieldB = models.CharField(max_length=64)

--admin.py--

class Form1(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AModel
        fields = ('fieldA',)

class Form2( ModelForm ):
    class Meta:
        model = AModel
        fields = ('fieldB',)
```

.... something add for make this two forms in one multipage admin form , is that possible? or any other way to do the same job.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible by using admin module. The only way is either some external plugins or you need to create custom admin views. Google around..